# Checkbox Value If name is dynamic

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox generated from database:

```
foreach($array as $value){

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="t' . $value . '" value="0"/>';

}
```

Question:

How can I get the values of these checkboxes?

I tried in this way:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
            $perm = $_REQUEST["t$value"];
}
```

But is not working. :(

Comment: It doesn't matter that all the values are 0, I just need the values.

Comment: first of all you could run `print_r($_REQUEST)` to make sure the fields are being posted, seccondly whenever i have doe this i use concatenation `$perm = $_REQUEST["t" . $value];`

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done, and it seems, that they are not, just the values I check. So then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To above written:
You also need check isset()

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($_REQUEST["t".$value]))
        $perm[$key] = $_REQUEST["t".$value];
}
var_dump($perm);
```

Or you can throws Warning exception if variable (array key) is not set. Because browser can send only checked values and skip unchecked in request.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following

```
foreach($array as $value){

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="t[]" value="' . $value . '"/>';

}
```

Then you can access all the choosed options in PHP as array with

```
$_REQUEST['t']
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to identify it based on the $value, I don't need a multiple checkbox.

Comment: A checkbox can only be `checked` or `not checked`. The values which are in the array are the checked ones. It's the same result but better for handling it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
            $perm = $_REQUEST["t".$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a associative array?

```
foreach($array as $value){

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="t['.$value.']" value="0"/>';

}
```

Then...

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
     $perm = $_REQUEST["t"][$value];
}
```